# Is this right way to release the connection?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

As you know Node.js statements are async. So I write code in following way. But I can't make sure if the connection is released or not.

Why, because I'm writing `connection.release()` just after `res.json()`. In my view, once we send response the control doesn't pass to next statement (Query **1**: Is it true?). So should I write it before I send response?

Query **2**: `res.json() / res.end()` and `connection.release()` both are async methods. Is it true?

Query **3**: Even if the following code works perfectly, can I write `connection.release()` only once, i.e., just when `if else` statement ends? **If yes, why doesn't `next()` works after res.end()` in Node.js?**

```
connection.query(query, [body.endDate, tripId], function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) {
        res.status(422).json(
            {
                status: "error",
                data: {error: {code: err.code, sqlMessage: err.sqlMessage}},
                message: "Something didn't work."
            }
        );
        connection.release();
    } else {
        res.status(200).json(
            {
                status: "success",
                data: {affectedRows: rows.affectedRows},
                message: "Trip ended."
            }
        );
        connection.release();
    }
});
```

Comment: Why do you release the connection at each request? If you do so, you should recreate it at the beginning of each request. Usually there is a connection pool that is used during the entire lifecycle of the application so  you don't have to release it.

Comment: Yes I pull a connection from pool for every request. I release it because when I didn't do so, connection limits exceeded.

Comment: Which library do you use?

Comment: mysql and express js

Comment: Ok I understand what you mean. You don't have to get a connection every time. You can just query directly from the pool [like so](https://github.com/mysqljs/mysql#pooling-connections). Getting a connection is useful when you want to apply a transaction for example.

Comment: What if my connection limit is 5 and there are 100 users accessing same API concurrently? Would only 5 users get data? Is this what connection limit means?

Comment: You are partially right. Yes if the connection limit is 5, only 5 users will get results concurrently. However, the option `waitForConnections` is true by default so the remaining users will wait for the connection pool to be free before the server serves the result (very short time for common query).

Comment: Sending a response doesn't miraculously stop executing any other code. So it's perfectly okay to add additional code _after_ `res.json()/res.send()/res.end()`. However, you can still only send _one_ response, so after you used one of those methods, you typically don't call `next()` because it will pass the request to other request handlers that may _also_ want to send back a response (which isn't allowed).

Comment: Does `next()` work after I write `res.end()` ?